# How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have copied the `sample.war` file into the `webapps` directory of Tomcat, and I can access `localhost:8080`.

Now how will Tomcat deploy it, I mean do I need to open it in browser? How can I access the application?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You can access your application from: `http://localhost:8080/sample`

Deploying or redeploying of war files is automatic by default - after copying/overwriting the file `sample.war`, check your `webapps` folder for an extracted folder `sample`.

If it doesn't open properly, check the log files (e.g. tomcat/logs/catalina.out) for problems with deployment.

Comment: what if the WAR is named "ROOT.war?" Where can I find that WAR?

Comment: What if I want to deploy my sample.war to localhost:8080/somethingdifferent ?

Comment: you can specify that in META-INF/context.xml

Comment: The META-INF/context.xml, is it the one in tomcat\conf\context.xml ? Or should it be in my application I am deploying?

Comment: it can be in both places. I prefer it to be within the application

Comment: @Bozho Unfortunately it doesn't work! Would you like to test my specific war file?! Please download "linshare-core-1.8.4-without-SSO.war" from "https://forge.linshare.org/projects/linshare/files".

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04.3 the webapps directory is located at /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps .

Answer (score 102):

step-1. here I'm deploying **pos.war** First go to tomcat webapps folder and paste it

[image]

step-2.  go to tomcat->**bin** folder  start tomcat by clicking **startup.bat**

step-3. go to browser write localhost:port/project name eg. **localhost:8080/pos** (here my tomcat run on port 8080)

Done....

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  

Additionally, I needed to set permissions to my newly installed Tomcat directory structure so that my WAR could be extracted and log files could be generated.

Answer (score 61):

You just need to put your war file in webapps and then start your server.

it will get deployed.

otherwise you can also use tomcat manager a webfront to upload & deploy  your war remotely.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work! Would you like to test my specific war file?! Please download "linshare-core-1.8.4-without-SSO.war" from "https://forge.linshare.org/projects/linshare/files"

Comment: @Mr.H tail the log when you start the server after placing war, you will find why it is not working

Comment: "If the Host autoDeploy attribute is "true", the Host will attempt to deploy and update web applications dynamically, as needed, for example if a new .WAR is dropped into the appBase. For this to work, the Host needs to have background processing enabled which is the default configuration. "

Answer (score 55):

#### Manual steps - Windows

1. Copy the .war file (E.g.: prj.war) to `%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps` ( E.g.: C:\tomcat\webapps )
2. Run `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat`
3. Your .war file will be extracted automatically to a **folder** that has the same name (without extension) (E.g.: prj)
4. Go to `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml` and take the **port** for the HTTP protocol. `<Connector port="8080" ... />`. The default value is **8080**.
5. Access the following URL:

   `[<protocol>://]localhost:<port>/folder/resourceName`

   (E.g.: `localhost:8080/folder/resourceName`)

Don't try to access the URL without the `resourceName` because it won't work if there is no file like `index.html`, or if there is no url pattern like "`/`" or "`/*`" in **web.xml**.

The available main paths are here: `[<protocol>://]localhost:<port>/manager/html` (E.g.: `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`) and they have `true` on the "Running" column.

---

#### Using the UI manager:

1. Go to `[<protocol>://]localhost:<port>/manager/html/` (usually `localhost:8080/manager/html/`)

   This is also achievable from `[<protocol>://]localhost:<port>` > **Manager App**)

   If you get:

   > 403 Access Denied

   go to `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\tomcat-users.xml` and check that you have enabled a line like this:

   ```
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-gui"/>
   ```
2. In the **Deploy** section, WAR file to deploy subsection, click on **Browse...**.

   [image: Deploy browse]
3. Select the .war file (E.g.: prj.war) > click on **Deploy**.
4. In the **Applications** section, you can see the name of your project (E.g.: prj).

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the ways already mentioned (dropping the war-file directly into the *webapps*-directory), if you have the Tomcat Manager -application installed, you can deploy war-files via browser too. To get to the manager, browse to the root of the server (in your case, localhost:8080), select "Tomcat Manager" (at this point, you need to know username and password for a Tomcat-user with "manager"-role, the users are defined in *tomcat-users.xml* in the *conf*-directory of the tomcat-installation). From the opening page, scroll downwards until you see the "Deploy"-part of the page, where you can click "browse" to select a WAR file to deploy from your local machine. After you've selected the file, click deploy. After a while the manager should inform you that the application has been deployed (and if everything went well, started).

[Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)'s a longer how-to and other instructions from the Tomcat 7 documentation pages.

Comment: The `manager` role in Tomcat 7 is now `manager-gui`. I got bitten by this one.

Comment: Dropping the .war file in webapps hasn't worked for me, and there was no sign of error in the logs. Doing it from the Tomcat Manager did the trick. Not a clue about why the first method failed

Answer (score 17):

There are two ways:

1. Either you can do hot deployment (Hot deployment means deploying when server is running/up).
2. Or you can do cold deployment (Cold deployment means deploying when server is stopped).

Just use tomcat manager console for console deployment or simply copy and paste your application in webapp folder of your server's tomcat_home directory.

**Note:** Make sure if your war file size is **more than 52 MB** (*the default configuration value*),
you need to make two little changes in web.xml file of Manager application of your webapp folder(Manager application is provided by Apache tomcat by default upon installing the server).

- Go to the web.xml of the manager application (for instance it could
      be under /tomcat7/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml.
- `Increase the max-file-size and max-request-size values in web.xml file:`

  `<multipart-config>`

  ```
      <!– 50MB max –>

      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>

      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>

      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>

   </multipart-config>
  ```

  Increase the size by putting the values for `<max-file-size>` and `<max-request-size>` according to your requirement.

Answer (score 10):

This has been working for me:

1. Create your war file (mysite.war) locally.
2. Rename it locally to something besides .war, like mysite.www
3. With tomcat still running, upload mysite.www to *webapps* directory.
4. After it finishes uploading, delete the previous version mysite.war
5. List the directory, watching for the directory /mysite to disappear.
6. Rename mysite.www to be mysite.war
7. List the directory, watching for the new /mysite to be created.

If you try uploading the new file as a war file, with tomcat still running, it will attempt to expand it before it is all there.  It will fail.  Having failed, it will not try again.  Thus, uploading a www file, then renaming it, allows the whole war file to be present before tomcat notices it.

Hint, don't forget to check that the war file's owner is tomcat (Use chown)

Comment: While this may work in exceptional cases,  it is not a valid undeployment / deployment procedure. mysite.www will create a new context if autodeploy="true" and deleting mysite.war deletes the mysite context under several normal conditions. The best reference is [Tomcat Web Application Deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you installed tomcat7 using `apt-get` in linux then, deploy your app to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`

eg.

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop

mvn clean package
sudo cp target/DestroyTheWorldWithPeace.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
#you might also want to make sure war file has permission (`777` not just `+x`)
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

Also, keep tailing the tomcat log so that you can verify that your app is actually making peace with tomcat.

```
tail -f /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
```

The deployed application should appear in `http://172.16.35.155:8080/manager/html`

Answer (score 5):

For deploying the war file over tomcat,
Follow the below steps :

1. Stop the tomcat. powershell->services.msc->OK->Apache Tomcat 8.5->stop(on left hand side).

[image]

2. Put the .war file inside E:\Tomcat_Installation\webapps i.e. webapps folder i.e. put.war (put.war is just an example)

[image]

3. After starting the tomcat(to start tomcat  powershell->services.msc->OK->Apache Tomcat 
   8.5->start )

you will get one folder inside E:\Tomcat_Installation\webapps**put**

[image]

In this way you can deploy your war file in Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

1.Generate a war file from your application 
2. open tomcat manager, go down the page
3. Click on browse to deploy the war.
4. choose your war file.
There you go!

Answer (score 2):

The application name goes into the context of your tomcat deployed URL,
eg. `http://localhost:Port/applicationName`.
If your application name is simple then, it should be `http://localhost:8080/sample`.

By default, Port is 8080, but if you wish to change it, or want to know the port where tomcat is running, simply go to `server.xml` file in `<tomcat-apache-dir>/conf/server.xml`, there you can find port & change,
eg. `<Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>`

If anything goes wrong, check the log files (e.g. `<tomcat-apache-dir>/logs/catalina.out`)

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps:

- Stop the Tomcat
- Right Click on Project and click on "Clean and Build"
- Go to your project Directory and inside Dist Folder you will get war file that you copy on your tomcat
- webApp Folder
- Start the tomcat
- automatic war file extract and run your project

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction in the following link, it works for me.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/487178/Tomcat/war-file-show-load

> 1. Stop Tomcat
> 2. Delete all the logs in **tomcat/logs** and all files in **tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost**
> 3. Remove the war file and the directory it created (if it did) from **tomact/webapps**
> 4. Start Tomcat
> 5. While watching the logs, copy the war file to the webapps directory again

After this, keep an eye on the **catalina.xxxx-xx-xx.log** to find out the issue.

Comment: This is not a valid undeployment / deployment procedure as it interferes with files exclusively managed by Tomcat. The best reference is [Tomcat Web Application Deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)