# Installing a game on Tomcat. Newb here

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

this might be a tall order or it might be ridiculously simple. I wanted to run this game on my website: https://github.com/ajanata/PretendYoureXyzzy

Unfortunately I have no clue how to make something like this work. There didn't seem to be an installation file, so I can only imagine it's painfully obvious to anyone familiar with this sort of thing. I recently ordered a trial of a shared Tomcat server, since I'm assuming that's needed to run all the Java goodies.

If there are any simple instructions I should follow to install this, it would be much appreciated if you could share them!

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the source from the Github [link](https://github.com/ajanata/PretendYoureXyzzy/zipball/master) you provided and then download [Eclipse - Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2). You then open Eclipse and choose `File->Import->General->Existing Projects Into Workspace` and choose the folder you just downloaded. You can then choose `Export->Web->WAR file` and export the WAR file.

You then download and setup Tomcat as described [here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html) (ignore the parts after Tomcat is running and you can access it at `http://localhost:8080`) and install the WAR as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-war-in-tomcat-7).

If you are feeling exceptionally lazy I have built the war [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/757z0w9w2ubv/n/cah_war). You just need to drop it into the `webapps` folder in your Tomcat installation and then restart your server. You can then access it at:

`http://localhost:8080/cah`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without looking deeper into the project, if they create a .war file somehow, just copy the .war file into [tomcat home]/webapps directory and your application will be deployed.  You can then acces it at yourmachine:8080/warname
where warname == the name of the war file without the .war extension.

There appears to be a SQL script with the project as well, not sure if there is some database you might need to setup which could get tricky.

Comment: I did read up enough to learn what .war files are and, unfortunately, I didn't see any associated with the project. Just an archive of files.

Comment: Do you have the source code loaded in Eclipse?  It's in the format of an Eclipse project, so assuming you have it loaded in Eclipse you should be able to right click > export > War File and select a location for the .war.