# Install Application on Tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat

I wrote a Java Application in IntelliJ Idea 13 and can start this application on a Tomcat 7 server. Now I want to test the application on a  Windows XP pc. So I installed Tomcat 7 and XAMPP(for database) on the Windows XP pc. I got some files in my .../target folder like "projectname-SNAPSHOT" folder, "projectname.war", "generated-sources" folder and so on. So do I have to put all these files to my Windows XP pc into the webapp folder from Tomcat and start Tomcat?  When I try it this way, I can't open the application when I go to "localhost:8080". 
What files are missing to start the Application? Or do I have to compile all the java files again on the XP pc?

Comment: in the tomcat log directory, please look at logs and see if it has any issue reported if so, please show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If things are built correctly and there are no external dependences (such as a database JDNI resource), you should be able to put "**projectname.war**" in the **/webapps** folder, start tomcat, and then browse to `http://localhost:8080/projectname`.

Comment: I have some maven dependencies, what do I do with them?

Comment: Maven dependencies should already be in the .war file under /WEB-INF/lib.  The .war file is really just a .zip file, so you could unzip it to verify what you do or don't have.

Answer (score 0):

`projectname.war` should be sufficient in your "webapps" folder for most cases. Tomcat should deploy this automatically.

See: [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7) for more information