# Where is my webapp deployed(From Eclipse to Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy my Web application(Dynamic web Project) from Eclipse to Tomcat 7( in Windows). Although the deployment works, I would like to see where exactly(the location) the web app is deployed. I did search for my webapp (named as 'Demo') in TOMCATINSTALLATION/**webapps** directory. But could not find my application('Demo') there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7

Comment: @GGrec He's deploying using Eclipse, not the war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click on the Eclipse Tomcat server instance and have a look at the configuration. If you are using the option "Use workspace metadata" then the app is deployed in a path like

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX/wtpwebapps/<context>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about particular Eclipse case, but usually IDE deployment works by dynamically overriding `CATALINA_BASE` environment variable and setting it to your project output folder. `CATALINA_BASE` tells Tomcat to search for your wepapps, server settings, etc. in the specified folder.

So answer to your question is that the actual working code sits somewhere in your project's build folder: subfolder `build` for regular projects or `target` for maven ones.