# how to run a spring application in tomcat without using eclipse etc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

my application is running in eclipse but i want to run it on tomcat .i want to run my spring application in tomcat server and don't want to use eclipse or any other tool, so how can i do that and where do i put my various files basically the directory of it, and the complete procedure to do that. 
main problem is in the directory structure and the path to be put in the tomcat server to run that application.  i tried but it gives the 404 error file not found ,as i am new to the spring framework explain in detail

Comment: Make sure your tomcat server is running even eclipse is closed or not.

Comment: yes the eclipse is closed

Comment: Is your apache is running?

Comment: yes apache is running

Comment: Okay, Once build your application in eclipse id copy build file from your project and deploy this build file from tomcat html manager from browser and try to access your project. can I see sample url what are you trying to access from tomcat.

Comment: As in your question you are saying that your project gives you `404` error this means your project has not deployed properly on web server.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a **very** broad question. But, in an attempt to point you in the right direction please see [this article](http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners#web-application-directory). The link given provides insight into the directory structure of your application.

Now as far as running "outside of eclipse" you should be able to export your project from the "File" menu as a "Web Application Archive" or "WAR" file. This file can then be placed under ${CATALINA_BASE}/webapps and be launched when you start your container.

If you are using a stock configuration and you have an archive named "myapp.war", you can access it on

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

I hope this information helps you get to where you need to go.

Answer (score 1):

First export the war file using eclipse as you are using eclipse.

Then follow the procedure

[How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)