# Project that under tomcat webapps folder can not be found

Tags: tomcat7

I would like to deploy my project on tomcat server.

When i develop the project, i using eclipse with tomcat, and everything is ok.

I would like to deploy directly to tomcat server now.

I put my project folder under tomcat's webapps folder, and restart tomcat server.

But it shows 404 error when i open http://localhost:8080/myproject/

why this happen, and how can i figure it out?

Comment: @Tiny Hi, when we deploy our project, we need to put our project folder under webapps, and restart server, right? But it shows 404 error

Comment: You need to put a *.war file into webapps folder, server restart is not necessary. To figure out what is happening check logs folder, particularly catalina file.

Comment: @Ivan Hi, ivan. i tried to put a *.war file into webapps folder, but it shows a 503 error, said this application is not available.

Comment: @Ivan i complete the project using eclipse, and everything is ok when i deploy it using the eclipse with tomcat

Comment: @Will Logs is what you need to check first, as I said ;)

Comment: @Ivan ok, i am going to check the logs right now.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5109112/1391249) question and answers cover this in great details.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward when you invoke Tomcat from within Eclipse. Please read the FAQ section at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ

It explains how if you start Tomcat from within Eclipse, the binaries of original directories of Tomcat are used, but the web apps etc are stored separately in the Eclipse Workspace.