# netbeans-how to use .war file of Restful webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, war

I've developed a `RESTful` web service in netbeans and it made a `.war` file for me. now where should i put it on my host, so that the others can use this webserice?

Comment: What kind of hosting service do you use?

Comment: @yole I''m using a download host

Comment: You have to deploy it in a Servlet Container like tomcat.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam could you please explain more?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a download host for hosting a Web application. You should use a service that lets you execute code on the server. [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) is one of the easiest ones to get started with.

Comment: but before buying this host, i asked them and they told me i can use webservices, why do u say i cant use?

Comment: You said yourself that you're using a "download host". I understood this as "a host that only lets you host files". If you say exactly which hosting service you're using, I might be able to say more specifically whether you can host a Java Web service there. Alternatively, why don't you contact your host and ask them for instructions?

Comment: suppose I want to use glassfish as `Servlet Container`. as I'm really a beginner in these fields, I've really mixed up! should my Servlet Container get installed on the server or on my pc?!!!, then how to deploy my web app(or webservice) via that? thanx for your help

Comment: Glassfish needs to be installed on the server. You can find documentation on deploying to Glassfish [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html). Also, all modern Java IDEs have Glassfish integration, so you can also deploy to Glassfish from your IDE.

Comment: thanx. I read that documentation but still have problems. I use Netbeans and it has GlassFish integration. I made my web app and then run GlassFish (`http://localhost:8080`). now i want to deply it to my host, but it doesnt ask me my domain address. I've mixed up!!! please help me more. thanx

Comment: Do you actually know that your host has Glassfish installed and that you have permissions to deploy applications there?

Comment: I will ask them tomorrow. 1. suppose it is not installed, is it possible for me to install? 2. now suppose it is installed. then what should i do?

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server machine, then yes, you can install it yourself. I don't use NetBeans, so I can't help you with instructions on deploying applications using it.

Comment: what about not using an IDE, I mean via glassfish admin console (`http://localhost:8080`)?

Comment: If you can access the admin console of the Glassfish instance installed on your server (not on localhost), then yes, you'll be able to deploy the application from there.

Comment: thanx, but its getting harder and harder!!! I just want to deploy my web app to my server host!!! what is your solution to do that? how do you do that yourself?

Comment: As I said in my answer, please consider using Google App Engine. I use it for my own personal projects.

Comment: should it be installed on the server, too? could you please give me a big picture of `Google App Engine` (how should i work with that)?

Comment: Sorry, this is getting too long. Google App Engine is installed on Google's servers. Please spend some time doing your own research.