# run web-project out side from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, war

I have problem running the web-project that I worte in eclipse that runs on tomcat (7.0.34).
in my program I have class that extends HttpServlet and in that, a method doGet.
if I start the tomcat server from the eclipse and than enter in my browser:
http://localhost:8080/test/test2?parameters...
(parameters is the ones I get in my program from HttpServletRequest request in the doGet)
and it work there.

now I want to export the project and be able to run it anywhere not from the eclipse or in my computer.
but I tried many things and also export to war file(that I haven't able to run it at all), and then start the bin/startup.bat in my tomcat folder and still nothing come up.

Comment: whats the exception you are facing??when you run startup.bat whats the exception?

Comment: I put the war file of the project in the webapps, the run startup.bat, and then I have no way to run the war file.
If I try to run >java -jar test.war, it ofcourse also not working because I dont have main file and this is the error: 
"no main manifest attribute, in test.war"

Comment: and all of this times the localhost:8080.... that I try to run also say:
webpage is not available,

Comment: whenever you copy your war file in webapps folder and then execute `startup.bat` if app is deployed successfully then you will see the extracted folder of same name as war (in webapps) and if you do not see that folder , there might be some exception you can check the logs at `tomcat/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7