# Can I host standard war apps on Railo

Tags: tomcat, war, railo

Can I deploy a regular web application (war) to Railo?  I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't turn up an answer.  I expect I'd reference it via host/app-name.

Comment: Please be aware that Railo is no longer supported and has several security vulnerabilities that have been fixed in Lucee. It is highly recommended that you upgrade to Lucee (lucee.org) as soon as possible.

Comment: oh?  I don't see any mention of security vulnerabilities anywhere.  Can you provide links?

Comment: Well, the Railo project doesn't have any information about them because that project is dead and no longer being updated at all.  You can read about one of the security vulnerabilities fixed in Lucee (Which is a fork of the Railo 4.2 codebase) here: http://lucee.org/blog/lucee-stable-release-security-update-included.html  In addition to security fixes, Lucee also has a large amount of updates since last year too.

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You deploy applications (WAR) to tomcat (or any other JEE server), not to Railo. Railo is itself an application that is deployed on a JEE server (tomcat).  And, yes, you can deploy multiple applications to the same JEE server (tomcat). They need to have unique URI's and/or ports to coexist.

Comment: Ok, perhaps a better question is "how?"  If I drop my war into the webapps directory, tomcat explodes it, but it's not accessible as it would be on a regular instance.

Comment: That is a completely different question and has nothing to do with Railo. Start here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5109112/1636917

Comment: Uh, I disagree.  I have a war.  I deploy it on tomcat, it works.  I deploy it on railo, it doesn't.  I would say that's related.

Comment: Railo is just an application within tomcat itself.  The version of tomcat that comes with Railo is probably the issue.  Tomcat is up to version 9 (http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) while Railo _which is now defunct_ came with version 7 (http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/).

Comment: You can't deploy wars onto Railo.  It's not a J2EE servlet container.  I think you're just confused since the Railo installer also installs Tomcat at the same time.  You need to be looking at Tomcat docs.