# deploy a java-ee application which was in openshift, on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, openshift, deploying

I'm new in Java EE and Tomcat.

I worked on a REST Java application in OpenShift with JBoss EWS 2.0 and I had no problem. Recently, we got a server that I have to run my web service on.

Following [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7), I went to my application root and used this command:

```
jar -cvf myapp.war *
```

Note that `myapp` is my application name for example.

I put the *.war* file to `/base/path/of/tomcat/webapps/` and went to Tomcat GUI App Manager.

I saw that Tomcat created a folder with my *.war* name and put files into it, so I started my app but when I went to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` it returned 404. However, in OpenShift, when I opened it (opened root path), it displayed the *index.html* insomuch my webservice path is not valid and  does not work.

please guide me and thank you for your time spent on my question.

Comment: As per usual: Any errors in the server logs? Is there anything of interest in the server logs?

Comment: no, everything seams work well. for example if I put text.html in myapp folder and open http://localhost:8080/myapp/text.html it opens but my app parts in seprate folder and i don't know how to access it

Comment: Well... then I can only guess it is something as silly as there either not being any index.html in the actual deployed war, the webapp name somehow being overridden to be something other than "myapp", or something similar simple thing to overlook. The logging should indicate which application are deployed and under which context name, is it 'myapp' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple.

there is two way to deploy a war file on tomcat with custom path

the first one is to 
renaming your war file to custom URL you want (for example the war file name is `java-web-app-1.0.war` and your path is `myapp` so you have to rename it to myapp.war)

and copy and put it under `{tomcat-path}/webapps/`, then the Tomcat/TomEE does its job. (it creates an empty directory with the same name of your war file)

after about 1 minutes you can check the path (in this example must be `localhost:8080/myapp` and see your war file was deployed)

the second one is to use Tomcat GUI.

go to `Web Application Manager` part.

it's a page like this:

[image]

in `Deploy` box just fill the `Context` field (it will be the custom path and in this case is `myapp`) and then choose the war file and push deploy button.(do not need to fill `XML Configuration file URL` field)

then it gives you a message like this:

[image]

this means your war file was deployed on the custom path.

Answer (score 0):

I have to write an answer because I can't comment.

I suggest to give us a copy of the web.xml file.

On another hand, you have to know that Tomcat is a Servlet Container and JBoss a full stack JEE server. If you have EJB in your web-app it will not works.

Answer (score 0):

AS Clément Duveau says an EJB application cannot be deployed in a Servlet container (like Tomcat). An EJB application needs to be deployed in an Application Server like JBoss, Wildfly, GlassFish, Weblogic, Websphere, TomEE, etc.

The most similar server to Tomcat (Java EE compliant) would be TomEE.

Suggestion: If you need to use Tomcat, you can change EJB for Spring Framework.

Comment: it runs on localhost with tomcat 7.0 and 8.0 but netbeans deploys it. so this means it is possible to deploy it on normal tomcat but i don't know how to do this

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan Do you mean that your application works in a local Tomcat when it is deployed by Netbeans? So, you problem is that  you don't know how to do a manual deployment?