# With what can i deploy a .jar file on a production server?

Tags: java, spring, deployment

Let's say i have a spring application and it all builds into a nice simple .jar file.

How can i, and with what tools, deploy this .jar file on a production server?

Comment: my question is only refeering to a spring application

Comment: i was thinking more the lines of a Procfile situation

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a war file using a application server, some thing like Tomcat, JBOSS, etc.,

Here is [**How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: Yes, i also can deploy a ruby on rails application using nginx

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the fastest way is to create a dokku instance, add a Procfile, and using git remotes push everything there.. nice

Answer (score -1):

1. first of all you have create executable jar like this
   C\mywork> jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class
2. manifest text file will have entry of main class like
   Main-Class: Craps
3. last step to execute this file either from command prompt or server configuration or directly clicking on jar file like.
   java -jar Craps.jar