# Servlet works in Eclipse, but not from my tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Im teaching myself servlets, found some very good tutorials and have great success in Eclipse Neon EE. (very basic servlet that just serves a simple static web page)

I installed Tomcat standalone before installing Eclipse Neon EE, and  tested it and I get the regulat apache tomcat page.  The tutorials I found also guided me on how to set up the tomcat server in Eclipse.  They also showed me how to create a project and servlet. Even though I use 3.1, I still have Eclipse create the web.xml file.

When I run my servlet, Eclipse starts up Tomcat and does everything, and opens a browser tab within Eclipse and it takes me to http://127.0.01:9999/first/Hello and it serves up my web page.  No problem.  So now I export my project as WAR file, tell Eclipse to put the .war file right in my tomcat8's ROOT dir.  Then i stop the tomcat8 server in eclipse and shut down eclipse.  Then I use startup.bat and tomcat comes up, but then I cannot surf to http://127.0.01:9999/first/Hello from this same PC, it just gives 404 with "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Im not quite sure what steps I am missing?

Comment: War files must go to the webapps dir. Not to the ROOT dir. ROOT is just one of the deployed webapps. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Deployment_With_Tomcat

Comment: Check this URL first  http://127.0.01:9999/ if it shows project deployed in tomcat console.War needs to to webapps folder to be accessible to application server

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your war file (first.war) into the "webapps" subdirectory, not into the root Folder of your tomcat server. Have a look at : [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)

> Copy the .war file (first.war) to %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps ( E.g.: C:\tomcat\webapps )
>
> Run %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
>
> Your .war file will be extracted automatically to a folder that has the same name (without extension) (E.g.: hello)
>
> ...