# How to deploy a Spring RESTful API on a Debian server?

Tags: java, spring, rest, web, debian

I built a RESTful api with Spring and it works like a charm in on my computer.
Now, i want to deploy the api on my VPS (Debian 7) but i don't know how to do it ! 
All tutorials enable on the internet work for eclipse on a windows computer, but not on a real distant server.
I heard that use TomCat will be a good start. However, i'm not confortable with servers.
Could you help me? (Sorry for my A1 english level)

Chill,
RastaPopuloS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .war file from your Spring project which can then be deployed on a tomcat server like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7).

Before, you need to install the tomcat application server which is pretty straightforward. E.g. you could follow these [instructions here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-tomcat-on-a-debian-server).

Comment: Ok, im gonna check this. Thanks for your answer !!