# How to upload dynamic web project to live server?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a project where i need to send a confirmation email to the user after completing registration form.
So i want to upload it to the live server. I want to know how do i eport my project to a folder, which i can then upload to a server.

Comment: Which IDE and build system (maven / gradel) you are using?

Comment: Im using eclipse. Not using any build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java Web project consist of servlet JSP. You need to create the war package of the project and you have to upload it to the webapps directory of the tomcat server.

Go to **file** >  **Export**  and export the project as a War file. Copy this war file and upload to the WebApps directory of the Tomcat on your server. restart the tomcat. you can access your web project.

This links will help you:

https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrewar.html

[How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: Does this procedure apply to hosting server.

Comment: Please Elaborate more your comment.

Comment: Ok. I have uploaded two php projects to the hosting server, thats simple just drag and drop your project files into root directory of hosting service. Now since the directory structure of java project in eclipse is different, i want to know how do i upload my java project to the hosting service. In simple terms how can i make my java project live on web.

Comment: Right now I am busy But Will update the answer soon.