# Run a Java Web-Application Project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, web-applications

i'm a C# Developer i currently just wanted to run a web application that was built in java.i really know nothing about java i installed Netbeans and Eclipse both in order to make it run. 
i have the source code from the production servers. when i try to build the project on Netbeans it successes but i wanna it to launch on the browser i dont know how. is there any guidance that i can follow in order to make this work 
i have never work with java i don't know the configuration very well

At the GlassFish Server output window i get the following:

> > Severe:   Exception while loading the app
>
> Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /Java Projects
>
> Severe:   Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid 'log4jConfigLocation'
>   parameter: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/log4j.properties] cannot
>   be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not
>   expanded?

Comment: you need a servlet container (like Tomcat) or an App server.

Comment: Look in your project for a file `web.xml`. This should contain a parameter like `<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>`. Does the value of this match the actual location of your `log4j.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- Install a servlet container like Tomcat and search your Netbeans
  project for a `.war` file and drop this into Tomcat's `webapps` folder.
  See [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7) for more details.
- Depending on what you installed with your version of Netbeans, you
  may be able to run the web app from within Netbeans. Right-click on
  your project and choose `Run`. See [Running a Web Application
  Project](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html#building)
  for more details.

Comment: The Glass Fish is installed i have many Apache servers on my pc im over whelmed at the moment

Comment: Ignore the Apache servers as you'll need a servlet container (eg. Tomcat) or an application server (eg. GlassFish). Try running your web app from within Netbeans to start with.

Comment: when i click run the project build and nothing happens! what should i Do ?!
i need the browser to pop up with the project