# Getting HTTP 500 error for ServletContainer class not found in Rest API using Postman

Tags: rest, jersey, war, tomcat8, servlet-container

I am very new to using Restful web services. I am trying to run a simple Restful API from Eclipse using Postman from Tutorialspoint UserManagement example.

I have created a WAR file using Eclipse, and to deploy war file into servlet container, based on what I have found out from the following link [instructions to deploy war file into tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7), you copy paste the war file into the webapp folder in apache tomcat 8.0.49 folder paste the following link in your web browser or Postman http://localhost:8080/RestAPI_UserManagement/rest/UserService/user .
[image]

But keep getting an

HTTP 500 error in Postman,

```
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Error instantiating servlet class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
        </p>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </body>
```

and in the Eclipse console I am getting the following error

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey Restful API
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've written the following code in my project folder(POJO class, Rest API, and business logic to implement Rest API). Here is the business login to implement Rest API and web.xml.

UserServices.java

```
package com.RestAPI;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Userservices")
public class UserServices {
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    @GET
    @Path("User")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userDao.getUserList();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0">
   <display-name>User Management</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Restful API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.RestAPI</param-value>
    </init-param>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Restful API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my file structure for my project. I have downloaded all of Jersey libraries into the /Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib path in my project.
[image]

Here is my catalina.out tomcat log.

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Roys_laptop/apache-tomcat-8.0.49/bin/catalina.sh: line 456: /usr/libexec/java_home:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk:/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Based on this my catalina.out tomcat log, it says there is some variable is missing. But I am not sure what that is, and how to set it. Some help please...

Comment: add the jersy2.x  jar org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: If you extract the contents of the war, are all the jars in the WEB-INF/lib?